# Possibility about conditional export ES6 module based on process.env.NODE_ENV?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, module, static, export

I wrote a utility library and I want to `tree-shaking` them when my user `publishes` their app.

In Webpack v4, you need to make your module `ES6` to support `tree-shaking`, but I also want to split my `development build` and my `production build` into different files.

What I want is exactly like react's NPM module:

```
// index.js
'use strict';

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports = require('./cjs/react.production.min.js');
} else {
  module.exports = require('./cjs/react.development.js');
}
```

This leads me questions.

If I make my utility modules all `commonjs`, I will never get `tree-shaking`, my app gets so huge.

If I make my utility modules all `ES6 static export`, I will have to include `development message` in `production code`.

And publishing two modules (eg: `my-utility` and `my-utility-es`) will not helping, because in development, my code looks like this:

```
import { someFunc } from 'my-utility';
```

but in production code, I will have to change it to this:

```
import { someFunc } from 'my-utility-es';
```

How can I solve this problem?

## Update

To be more clear, my `development build` and `production build` contains different source code **(eg: production build has stripped all error message)**.

So specify webpack mode isn't satisfying for me.

Comment: You cannot get tree-shaking using es5/commonJS module.exports syntax. But as shared below, you can use webpack --mode to remove the "development" portions of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found out the answer by myself, I think the best way to do this is through `babel macros`:

```js
import { something } from 'myLibrary/macro';

// In webpack development:
// ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓
// import { something } from 'myLibrary/development';

// In webpack production:
// ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓
// import { something } from 'myLibrary/production';
```

My macro implementation:

```
import { createMacro } from 'babel-plugin-macros';

function macro({ references, state, babel }) {
  state.file.path.node.body.forEach(node => {
    if (node.type === 'ImportDeclaration') {
      if (node.source.value.includes('myLibrary/macro')) {
        if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
          node.source.value = 'myLibrary/module/production';
        } else {
          node.source.value = 'myLibrary/module/development';
        }
      }
    }
  });

  return { keepImports: true };
}

export default createMacro(macro);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the best solution I've found, without requiring the user to use Babel macros...

### Let's say:

- Our library is called `crazy-components`
- It exports two React components called `ComponentA` and `ComponentB`
- The components use code fencing to do some logging in dev mode only

```js
// src/index.js
import React from 'react';

export function ComponentA(props) {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    console.log(`Rendering ComponentA with props ${props}`);
  }

  return <div>ComponentA message: {props.msg}</div>;
}

export function ComponentB(props) {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    console.log(`Rendering ComponentB with props ${props}`);
  }

  return <div>ComponentB message: {props.msg}</div>;
}
```

### We want the the library to:

1. Be tree-shakable, so if user does `import { ComponentA } from 'crazy-components'`, the code for `ComponentB` does not end up in their bundle.
2. The logging code is stripped from production bundles.

### Solution

#### 1. Bundle library with Rollup

#### 2. Configure Rollup to create both CJS and ESM builds in both production and dev versions (production versions with logging code stripped etc).

CJS builds are output to `/dist/cjs`, ESM builds to `/dist/esm`. Files are called `crazy-components.prod.min.js` and `crazy-components.dev.js`.

Only the dev builds contains the logging code (not explaining how to do all this, if you're reading this, you probably already know).

#### 3. Create entry points for CJS and ESM as follows:

```js
// index.js
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    module.exports = require('./dist/cjs/crazy-components.min.js');
} else {
    module.exports = require('./dist/cjs/crazy-components.js');
}
```

```js
// es/index.js
import {
    ComponentA as ComponentA_prod,
    ComponentB as ComponentA_prod
} from '../dist/esm/crazy-components.prod.min.js';

import {
    ComponentA as ComponentA_dev,
    ComponentB as ComponentA_dev
} from '../dist/esm/crazy-components.dev.js';

export const ComponentA = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? ComponentA_prod : ComponentA_dev;
export const ComponentB = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? ComponentB_prod : ComponentB_dev;
```

#### 4. Point to both entry points in `package.json`:

```
// package.json
{
  "name": "crazy-components",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "module": "es/index.js",
  "sideEffects": false
}
```

#### 5. (optional) Make importable as ESM in NodeJS

Node 12 (with flag) and Node 13+ [support ES modules natively](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/esm.html).

Add to `package.json`:

```
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./es/index.js",
      "require": "./index.js"
    },
    "./es": "./es/index.js"
  },
```

Add extra `package.json` file in `es` folder to flag contents of the folder as ESM to NodeJS:

```
// es/package.json
{
  "type": "module"
}
```

Use [rollup-plugin-copy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-copy) to get Rollup to also copy this file into `dist/esm`:

```js
// rollup.config.js
import copy from 'rollup-plugin-copy';
/* ... other imports ... */

export default {
  input: 'src/index.js',
  /* ... other config ... */
  plugins: [
    /* ... other plugins ... */
    copy({targets: [{src: 'es/package.json', dest: 'dist/esm'}]})
  ]
};
```

### Possible improvements

`es/index.js` is created by hand, so if you later add `ComponentC`, it also needs to be added to `es/index.js`. It'd be ideal if there was a Rollup plugin to automate creation of `es/index.js`, but I haven't found one.

Also, your mileage may vary. I've only just been trying this out today. It seems to work as you'd expect when the library is imported in a [create-react-app](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-app) app, but I've not tested it with hand-coded Webpack configs.

This approach should be generalisable to any library, not just React components, but I've not tried.

Any suggestions for improvements very welcome!

Answer (score -2):

All you need to solve this problem is to use [`mode`](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/mode/).  See [Specify the Mode](https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/#specify-the-mode).

> Since webpack v4, specifying mode automatically configures DefinePlugin for you:

**webpack.prod.js**

```
  const merge = require('webpack-merge');
  const common = require('./webpack.common.js');

  module.exports = merge(common, {
    mode: 'production',
  });
```

They mention React by name:

> If you're using a library like react, you should actually see a significant drop in bundle size after adding this plugin.

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't answer my question, I've updated my question.